# How can I get the revision number into an Ant property in Luntbuild?

Tags: ant, continuous-integration, ognl, luntbuild

I'm sure this must be possible:

I want to have the revision number (from Subversion) put into a property that is accessible from Ant when my build runs in Luntbuild.  There must be an OGNL expression that I can add to the Build Properties box on the configuration page for my Ant builder.

Does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find using either the [SvnAnt](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant.html) or [svntask](http://code.google.com/p/svntask/) Ant tasks to get the Subversion revision number directly in your Ant script might be a valid alternative.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that, but it seems like this should be possible, using Luntbuild.

Comment: Well, this wasn't the answer I was hoping for, but since you suggested it, and no one else suggested a way to do this strictly inside LuntBuild, I suppose it might not be possible.  Thanks for helping me confirm it!