# Ant Build Read version number from svn log output

Tags: regex, eclipse, svn, ant

Requirement:

Run `svn log -l 1` command and this will have an output like this.

> ```
>     ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>     r2633 | name | 2012-11-07 17:28:20 +0530 (Wed, 07 Nov 2012) | 1 line
>     My comment.
>     ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

I need to extract the revision number 2633 and assign this as a property. I would prefer to avoid ant-contrib.

What I tried:

```
<echo>Run svn log -l 1</echo>
<exec executable="svn" outputproperty="svn.output" failonerror="false">
    <arg line="log -l 1"/>
</exec>   
<echo message="Output was: ${svn.output}" />
```

This gets the above output inside the property ${svn.ouput} but am not sure how do I extract version from this.

Other option is to write the variable in file, but again how do I extract the version into a property?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: svn log -q -l 1 will be better. Can you use pipes inside exec some way?

Comment: svn log | grep r | gawk {'print $1'} or write **pure revision** into file with subwcrev

Comment: I am doing it on windows so cant use grep. But thanks for suggestion.

Comment: unixtools (ports of some tools) have grep and gawk

Comment: When you actually only want the revision number, see the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065130/how-can-i-get-the-revision-number-into-an-ant-property-in-luntbuild

Comment: @mthomas Thanks for suggestion. However I would not like to add any dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a clean way to pull out a substring from a property in standard Ant.  See [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945374/how-to-pull-out-a-substring-in-ant) for some alternative solutions.

Comment: That is true. Thanks for the link, I had referred that earlier. I was wondering if using file to write output and then read the data required using regex would be better. I would like to avoid any more dependencies.

Comment: The fourth answer in the link does exactly that - writes a temp. file and searches it with a regex.